# Define a function : Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: fibonacci

Define a function to implement Fibonacci Sequence: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34. Please use the function output first 20 figures of Fibonacci Sequence.

Comment: Please share to what level you've tried. We can help you from where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python implementation

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()

fib(5000)
```

**Output**

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181
```

A recursive implementation

```
memo = [-1] * 21
memo[0] = 0
memo[1] = 1
print(memo[0], end=' ')
print(memo[1], end=' ')

def fibrec(n):
    if(memo[n] == -1):
        memo[n] = fibrec(n-2) + fibrec(n-1)
        print(memo[n], end=' ')

    return memo[n]

fibrec(20)
```

**Output**

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765
```